# How to present in a ListView the data which is stored in a SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

In my application, I created Favorite Contacts about 3 which I choose from the existing contacts from the device. I'm able to successfully store the FAV Contacts on to the SharedPreferences with Name and PhoneNo and also able to retrieve that information and present it in the TextView. But What I want is to present that data in a List View with a custom_row layout after that. (I've used the TextView stuff to ensure that I can retrieve it correctly - small test for myself)

**where I need help is "To present the FAV Contacts data in a ListView which I retrieve from the SharedPreferences"**. I'm showing my code where I'm able to present the data in a TextView. I would be glad if you guys can suggest me how to put that on to the ListView...

Below is the Code Snippet:

```
public class FavContacts_Activity extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView title, tV_Contacts_list;
Button go_Back_to_ContactsList;
ListView imp_Contacts_List;
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "PACKAGE";
SharedPreferences preferences;
String [] imp_Contacts = {};
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
int count = 0, i = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.favcontacts_list);
        title = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.contacts_title);
        tV_Contacts_list = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tV_Contacts_list);
        imp_Contacts_List = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.listView1);
        go_Back_to_ContactsList = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btn_Back);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, imp_Contacts);


        preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        for (count = 0; count <3; count++) {
            String contacts_list = preferences.getString("CONTACT "+count, null);
            tV_Contacts_list.setTextSize(15);
            tV_Contacts_list.append("\n       "+ i +". "+ contacts_list);
            imp_Contacts_List.setAdapter(adapter);
            i++;
        }

        go_Back_to_ContactsList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Let me know if other part of the code is required where I store the FAV Contacts on to the SharedPreferences through AlertDialogs..

and below is the screen-snapshot:
[image: Emulator Screenshot showing the data]

Comment: You should learn about custom listviews [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) because if you can understand how to work with custom listviews...i am sure you wont have any problem with this

Comment: Thanks @1baga for the link. Appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why you were setting the adapter in the loop, but here's an example how create an adapter with your contacts and then use it to populate a listview with custom rows:

```
preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();
// Loop through the shared prefs, adding contacts to our List
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String contacts_list = preferences.getString("CONTACT "+i, null);
    contacts.add((i+1)+". "+contacts_list);
}

// Create the adapter with contacts
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.listview_row, R.id.list_item,  contacts);

// Populate the list
imp_Contacts_List.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Your custom listview's row, **listview_row.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTE**:
Make sure you have a listview with `android:id="@+id/imp_Contacts_List"` inside of your **favcontacts_list.xml**.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks @user3249477. One more thing is I would like to add numbers like 1, 2, 3 to the list_row items instead of just having the name n phoneNo...Can that be done., if so please help with a hint..

Comment: If I understand correctly you can just change to this: `contacts.add((i+1)+". "+contacts_list);` I'll update the answer demonstrating this.

Comment: Cool..u got it right...Looks like i can play with things passed to add() the way i want...for the UI. Appreciate the support Master !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `adapter.add(data);` and `adapter.remove(data);` methods to modify data in adapter.

Try this-

```
    preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    for (count = 0; count <3; count++) {
        String contacts_list = preferences.getString("CONTACT "+count, null);
        adapter.add(contacts_list);
        tV_Contacts_list.setTextSize(15);
        tV_Contacts_list.append("\n       "+ i +". "+ contacts_list);
        i++;
    }
    imp_Contacts_List.setAdapter(adapter);
```